# Ao tentar instalar app ele trava na mensagem "Preparing debugger support for iPhone"

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

Não consigo instalar a minha app no iPhone fico preso nesta mensagem:

> "Preparing debugger support for iPhone"

Imagem ilustrativa:

[image: Preparing debugger support for iPhone - ilustrativa apenas]

[Tentei todas as respostas a esta pergunta e nada resultou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316373/xcode9-iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone)

A seguir a esta mensagem dá me este erro (ou semelhante):

> itunes could not connect to iphone

Estou a usar uma máquina virtual Mac.

Comment: Adicionei a imagem para que as pessoas entendam "como ocorre".

Comment: Obrigado é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após longas horas de pesquisa e descobri que o meu *VirtualBox* estava a conectar os dispositivos por **USB 1.0**

Assim que instalei o `Extensions Pack` e mudei para `USB 2.0` a app já passou para o iPhone.